# limsup of a combined sequence where one term converges to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n, b_n$ be two positive sequences such that $a_n \rightarrow 0$. Is it generally true that $$\limsup{\sqrt[n]{a_n + b_n}} = \limsup{\sqrt[n]{b_n}}$$
? I know that without the nth root one could separate the existing limit but I stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, one needs additional information on the relative speeds of $a_n$ and $b_n$. For example, what happens when $a_n = b_n$ ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then in that case $\lim{\sqrt[n]{2a_n}} = \lim{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}$

Comment: Ah that's a good point, bad example on my part. Then take $b_n = \frac{1}{e^n}$ and $a=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: If you have positive sequences going to zero, then the limit will be whichever is the "bigger" of the two (bigger meaning in the big-O sense)

Comment: Thank you, that's a valid counterexample. Then, according to your last comment, the statement should certainly hold when the right hand side is greater than some positive number. Can you give me a hint on how to show this?

Comment: Suppose $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$$ Now pull out $b_n$ from the root and see what happens.

Comment: Now I see it. Thank you for your help!